# add a scale bar to a microscopy image?

Tags: image

Is there any way to add scale bar to a image for example. I just need to add a bar and a text on top of it to all my images without having to rewrite

```
Graphics[{Thick, Thick, Yellow, Line[{{100, 100}, {166, 100}}], 
        Text[Style["10 μ", Yellow, Bold, 25], {120, 110}]}]
```

for every image.

I just want to put this bar and text at left corner of the images I have.

[image: 1]

Comment: I'm soooo  photogenic!

Comment: But ... do you want to measure the white bar and resize your yellow scale accordingly?

Comment: Sorry Yes! I do want to change the numneric as the size of the bar varies. But how can I do that in terms of the horizontal pixel of the image. lets say its a 640x480 image. And a 100 pixels in 640 relates to 10 micron. If I change the bar length to 200 it should show 20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you have this image is in the same directory that your notebook with the name im.jpg, try this:

```
im = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "im.jpg"];
Show[{im}, 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Graphics[{Thick, Thick, Yellow, 
     Line[{{100, 100}, {166, 100}}], 
     Text[Style["10 \[Mu]", Yellow, Bold, 25], {120, 110}]}], 
   Scaled[{0.15, 0.9}]]]
```

The result is here:[image]